# Unable to select data from MySQL database using PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

Please I haven't quite figured out what's wrong with this code

```
<?php $servername = "blee.com";
$username= "free";
$password = "free";
$dbname = "one";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { 
        echo "success";
} else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error; 
}
$conn->close();    ?>
```

Somehow, if I try to insert anything into the database, it works perfectly, but if I try to select, it just shows "error creating table :" with no error being displayed...... I've searched all over but found no solution
    I'm using php7.2 on my web server

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue. Make sure you've granted the right privileges

Answer (score 10):

For `SELECT` (as well as `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` and `EXPLAIN`) queries [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [`mysqli::result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object if it succeeds, not a boolean. So your test

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
```

will always fail. What you should do instead is check that the query didn't fail (by comparing the return value with `false`), then you can use the returned object to fetch rows from the result set by using functions such as [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result !== false) { 
    // do something with results e.g.
    // while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { print_r($row); }
}
```

Comment: To be precise, `mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli::result` object that you can use to fetch rows from a resultset.

Comment: @RiggsFolly good point. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Wow, checking if the query didn't fail worked...... Thanks you guys, appreciate it........